# How does one have the C# designer know the default property for a Padding or other object/struct in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, attributes, default-value

How does one tell the designer the default value of a Property when it is not one of the types supported by `DefaultValue()`? For instance, a `Padding`, or a `Font`.

Normally, when you use a Windows Forms control, the default values will be in a normal font in the Properties window, and changed (non-default) values will be in bold. E.g.

[image: Image of properties windows with non-default values in bold]

In this sample, the default value of `ShowAddress` is `false` and the default value of `ShowName` is `true`. This effect is achieved with the following:

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool ShowAddress {
  get { return mShowAddress; }
  set { 
    mShowAddress = value; 
    Invalidate();
  }
}

[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ShowName { ... }
```

However, when I tried to do something for `Padding`, I failed miserably:

```
[DefaultValue(new Padding(2))]
public Padding LabelPadding { ... }
```

Which of course won't compile.

How on Earth would I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static Padding DefaultLabelPadding = new Padding(2);
private internalLabelPadding = DefaultLabelPadding;
public Padding LabelPadding { get { return internalLabelPadding; } set { internalLabelPadding = value; LayoutNow(); } }

// next comes the magic
bool ShouldSerializeLabelPadding() { return LabelPadding != DefaultLabelPadding; }
```

The property browser looks for a function named `ShouldSerializeXYZ` for each property `XYZ`.  Whenever `ShouldSerializeXYZ` returns false, it doesn't write anything during code generation.

EDIT: documentation:

- [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx
- [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Using Visual C# 2008. After putting in the code it wrote the property to the form designer, after setting it back to the default, and never took away the bolding in the Properties Window.

Comment: Sorry, I had the naming wrong.  I also added a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
[DefaultValue( typeof( Padding ), "2, 2, 2, 2" )]
public Padding LabelPadding
{
    get { return _labelPadding; }
    set { _labelPadding = value; }
}
```