# How to use DefaultValueAtribute class for a Font type in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I would like to know which is the proper string syntax that I must use to specify a value for the **[DefaultValueAtribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** class for a **Font** type in order to show that value as non-bold in the Visual Studio's designer property grid.

This is what I tried:

**C#:**

```
public class MyControl : UserControl {

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Font), "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt")]
    public override Font Font {
        get { }
        set { }
    }
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```vb
Public Class MyControl : Inherits UserControl

    <DefaultValue(GetType(Font), "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt")>
    Public Overrides Property Font As Font
        ...
    End Property

End Class
```

...However, the default font string is shown in **Bold** in the Visual Studio's property grid of my control.

Please note that I'm clearly searching for the correct parsing string, not for [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339704/1248295) or [ShouldSerializeFOO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340240/1248295) tricky ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just forget to set initial value of the `Font` property to the default value, so the control will use its parent font which is different from your desired default value and will be shown in bold.

You can set the font default value this way:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private const string MyDefaultFont = "Tahoma, 10pt";
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Font = (Font)new FontConverter().ConvertFromString(MyDefaultFont);
    }
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Font), MyDefaultFont)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get { return base.Font; }
        set { base.Font = value; }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `Control.Font` is [ambient property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) and if you don't assign any value explicitly to `Font` property, then it will not be serialized and the control will use its parent `Font` property. If you want some control use a different font than it's parent `Font`, it's enough to assign font to it. So it seems you don't need to assign any default font to child controls at all.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your solution works too, however in my case I'm not using a backing field (in @MrGadget answer comments I explained why). Anyways I can adapt my code to use a backing field, however the value of the backing field must be assigned like: **Font MyDefaultFont = Control.DefaultFont** property instead of hardcoding a custom default font name, and doing that the **DefaultValueAttribute** class seems doesn't recognize the font "**Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25**" (which is what I get from **Control.DefaultFont** property). I hope you did understood me (my English is not too good)

Comment: `Control.Font` is [ambient property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) and if you don't assign any value explicitly to `Font` property, then it will not be serialized and the control will use its parent `Font` property. If you want some control use a different font than it's parent `Font`, it's enough to assign font to it. So it seems you don't need to assign any default font to child controls at all.

Comment: Based on my previous comment, you don't need to set a font for your controls at all, but if for any reason you want to assign a font like `Control.DefaultFont` as default value for your font property, then the only solution for prevent serialization of the font, is using `ShouldSerializeFont` which you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this with a form with a PropertyGrid.  Perhaps you weren't setting an initial value in your private backing field?

```
Public Class MainWindow
    Private Sub MainWindow_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim MC As New MyControl
        Me.PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = MC
    End Sub

    Public Class MyControl : Inherits UserControl
        Private _Font As Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25)

        <DefaultValue(GetType(Font), "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25")>
        Public Overrides Property Font() As Font
            Get
                Return _Font
            End Get
            Set
                _Font = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm not using a backing field, I just overriden the **Font** property for take advantage of its setter method to "synchronize" the assigned font with the Font property of a child control, please see to understand what I mean (it's a very short code): http://pastebin.com/PRWS9xG7  in my code the DefaultValue Attribute doesn't have any effect, I don't know why, since I'm specifying the proper default font that is used by the UserControl.

Comment: In your constructor, add `MyBase.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25)` ?